# In opencv-python Image stitching How to eliminate the foreground moving objects from multiple images

Tags: opencv, image-stitching

Assume I have two images (like panorama) and I need to stitch these images together but the moving foreground images of people should not be present in the result image.Only background info should be present.

I am using Sift to detect keypoints and features, identifying the matches, then using getPerspectiveTransform method to find the transformation matrix.
Then using warpPerspective method by passing this transformation matrix as one of the arguments and finding the stitched image.

But how do I implement the logic for eliminating the foreground moving object.

Comment: pixelwise median. if background is visible in the majority of instances of that pixel, you'll get background.

Comment: so this has to be done even before finding the closest matches between image A and image B sift key points ?

Comment: no, you can do the feature matching before that. RANSAC finds the homography and it'll work as long as the background has "enough" matches, which needn't even be a majority of matches. -- if the camera *didn't move* relative to the background, you'd have an easier task.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitzThanks for the reply Chris....If possible can you share any useful links thats discusses this topic. I am still not sure of how to implement it

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz also..when you say "if background is visible in majority of instance of that pixel" in this case I should have more atleast 3 images and compare the pixel value from those three images and  see for majority appearances right.......but in mycase I only have two images. So If I get a pixel value of (say a person standing) in image A and actual background in that pixel from imageB , now there is no majority to choose from right....how do I decide to go with image B pixel value

Comment: in that case, there's no "decision" because you can't tell from the pixels alone. you could blend both 50:50, or you could employ some content-aware magic that "knows" (knows "human" objects or is trained to know what you want). or good old pyramid schemes to make it smooth: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dff/tutorial_py_pyramids.html

Comment: Let me know if these approaches makes sense..                                           
   1)histogram of those area and if its a background then there is going to be not much variations but if foreground then so much variation.
2)edge detection around that blob doesnt give  many edges in one image and gives so much edges in other image. Choosing from one image which doesnt give much